# Check is internet connection is working from PHP

Tags: php

I need to check if internet connection is effectively working in PHP.

I'm using this code:

```
function hasConnection() {  
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
    curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Or this code:

```
function hasConnection(){
    exec("ping -c 1 google.com", $output, $result);
    return ($result===0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Generally two codes are working. But [in this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/312936) a read that `ping` is not always sure for check internet connection.

It's cURL a sure/true way for check that? There is one more sure/true way?

Comment: You should better do dns lookup instead, like traceroute. A http status code can only be obtained if you have a connection. So your curl is more worse than your ping.

Comment: @7threeIt is precisely what I want, to know if there is an effective connection.

Answer (score 3):

Ping and traceroute only tell you whether or not the server is there NOT the service you want/need. If all you care about is whether or not a server is there/reachable then ping should be fine. If you care whether or not a particular service, like a web server is there, then cURL is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes my words exactly but he said "check internet connection" so I would check ip of a dns server not dns itself because of internal redirection of hosts in some rar cases... but nevermind ;)

Comment: I want to know if there is an **effective** internet connection avaliable (if i can navigate to internet). In the case of ping, this can be blocked or not avaliable... then i'm asking for one more safe/true way to check that.

Comment: Well if I were you I would use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php